# Rewrite rule not working for redirection from http to https

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewrite-module

Tried below code but it's not working, entered rewrite tag in system.webServer tag in web.config file of c# , Shows error rewrite can not be child element of system.webServer tag, I have also configured this rule in IIS

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Rule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you provide us with your full Web.config, removing any sensitive information?

Comment: Have you installed the URL rewrite module in IIS?

Comment: @MatthewEvans I have installed URL rewrite module in IIS and also configured it already

Comment: @ColinM this is sample code from web config: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration><system.webServer><rewrite >...rule...</rewrite></system.webServer></configuration>

Comment: First thing, put that in your question, not a comment. Secondly, have you tried configuring this rule via the IIS management console -> URL Rewrite?

Comment: @ColinM : Thanks for replying, i have configured this from iis console, and when we directly open https url it works fine but when we request for http url it not redirects to https and gives error like 'ERR_CONNECTION_RESET'

Answer (score 0):

Install Urlrewrite module if its not installed using web platform installer and try to manually add rule using urlrewrite module.

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-platform-installer

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Regards,
Jalpa.